# Extend the class or create an instance?

Tags: php, object-oriented, project-structure

I'm reading [Pro PHP and jQuery](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1430228474) and want to rebuild the example. The author is creating a database connection class:

```
class DB_Connect {

protected $db;

protected function __construct($dbo = NULL){
     if (is_object($db)) {
          $this->db = $db;
     }
     else {
          // Constants are defined in /sys/config/db-cred.inc.php
          $dsn = "mysql:host=" . DB_HOST . ";dbname=" . DB_NAME;
          try {
              $this->db = new PDO($dsn, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
          }
          catch (Exception $e) {
              die ($e->getMessage());
          }
     }
}
```

This class is then extended by the application's main class, in order to get access to the database object.

Why is this done that way? Couldn't we rather create an instance of `DB_Connect` in the main class? What are the benefits of that approach?

Comment: Do you mean `$dbo` instead of `$db`?

Comment: Has the book explained why you would extend any class? Don't focus on the example too much.

Comment: The only explanation was, as mentioned, to give the class access to the database object.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you see there is a classic rookie mistake, establishing an *[is-a](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a)* relationship (creating a subclass) between two classes when the actual relationship is *[has-a](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Has-a)* (instantiating a class as a member).  It's unfortunate that this mistake made it into print.

If the as-stated purpose of `Main` holds true, its purpose is to be a central module for an application.  It is not, in and of itself, something that establishes a database connection and you wouldn't instantiate a `Main` to do that.  The easy test for this is to say the two alternatives aloud and see which rings true.  For example:

- "A `Car` is a `Wheel`" (subclassing) doesn't make sense, because cars aren't wheels.  If you had to model four- and three-wheeled cars, you'd draw a complete blank on how to do that with subclassing.
- "A `Car` has a `Wheel`" (instantiation) works because cars are composed of (among other things) one or more wheels.  Envisioning a `FourWheeledCar` and a `ThreeWheeledCar` containing multiple instances of `Wheel` would be easy: one class has four instances of `Wheel` and the other has three.

Comment: Thank you very much for this great answer. Pretty disappointing to see such a mistake in this book, which i believed was one of the better ones on this topic.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't say that it's a good design to extend the Main application class from DB_Connect for the following reasons:

1. Inheritance should only be used, if the subclass can be used behaviorally equal to the Superclass, which is not the case in your example (See [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle))
2. Since LSP is violated and a DB is from a behavioral point of view used by the Main class, it's a classical use case for Composition, i.e. creating an instance of DB_Connect in the Main class as you suggested.

Your problem is a common design issue and is dealed with in the design principle ["Composition over Inheritance"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

Comment: Thank you too, gonna read through those links and throwing my book away :)